# pass parameters as POST through path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path

I currently have the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'New campus', new_campus_path(:university_id => @university.id) %>
```

and the url I get is:

```
/campus/new?university_id=1
```

How can I pass the parameter as POST?

I tried adding method => :post, but no luck there. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `method` parameter of `link_to` should work - what exactly was wrong with it?

```
<%= link_to 'New campus', new_campus_path(:university_id => @university.id), method: :post %>
```

Alternatively, you can try [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

```
<%= button_to 'New campus', new_campus_path(:university_id => @university.id), method: :post %>
```

---

Edit: in both of these cases, the paremeter will still be added to the query string, but as long as the HTTP verb is correct, this shouldn't make a difference for rails, because access to both is done through the `params` hash.

If it's really important to not include the parameter, you can create the form yourself and add a hidden field:

```
<%= form_tag new_campus_path, method: :post %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :university_id, @university.id %>
  <%= submit_tag 'New campus' %>
<% end %>
```

I don't think there's a shortcut for this in rails

---

Edit 2: As an aside, if I'm guessing correctly, this link is supposed to open a form for creating a new campus with a default university selected. If that's the case, you should really be using GET, because it's just a read action that doesn't cause any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery. Like this :

```
$("#my_link").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/campus/new?university_id=1'
  });
});
```

You can see the doc here : http://api.jquery.com/click/ and here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.